# How to instruct MongoDB that sub-document should be an Array not an Object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Assuming this Schema:

```
const Item = new Schema ({
  ids: [ Array ]
})
```

My `ids` is a 2d-array. If I initialize `ids` to `[[0]]` then I work with it just like any array. Example:

`$set: { 'ids.0.2': 5 }` would result in `ids` becoming `[ [0, 0, 5] ]`

But if I try to $set outside the range that's already been set to an Array, MongoDB creates an object there. Example:

`$set: { 'ids.1.0': 9 }` now `ids` is `[ [0, 0, 5], {"0": 9} ]`

How can I tell MongoDB (or Mongoose) to treat it like an Array?

Comment: Is this what you want `$push: { ids: [0,0,9] }` ?

Comment: Not really. I'm either using $set (only first time) or $inc. doing $push would require me to read it first, which I'm not.